# Laravel Job Queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel job which is made up of several stages, each stage dependant on the stage that came before it.

Im worried that if the job failed after say the first stage that when the job was retried it would try and redo the first stage (which can't happen)

The solution I thought Id found was to add a `$jobStage` property to the job and increment it after each successful stage was completed, which means that in the retry it can resume from the place it left off.

Unfortunately when the job is serialised back onto the redis queue the `$jobStage` is still at its initial 0 value.

I was wondering if there was a way to have changes to job properties persist between tries.

I have tried giving the properties initial values and tried setting them from the constructor....

Comment: I would split the job, so each stage is a job on its own, and they fire each other. Do you still have this issue? and have you tried that?